# Create Customize cloning , copying old to new record

Tags: apex, sobject, clone, sobjecttype, dynamic-apex

UPDATE:
AFter I have tried with the @Adrian approach I'm getting the following error now:

> |EXCEPTION_THROWN|[65]|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First
>   exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value
>   found: unknown duplicates value on record with id: a1cV00000005bDm: []
>   |FATAL_ERROR|System.DmlException: Insert failed.
>   First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate
>   value found: unknown duplicates value on record with id:
>   a1cV00000005bDm: []

Here is my code that executing my soql query

```
SObject existingRecord = Database.query('Select name, field2, field3....from where id='xyz'); 
SObject newRecord = sObjectId.getSObjectType().newSObject(sObjectId);

newRecord = existingRecord.clone(false, false, false, false);
insert newRecord;
```

UPDATE END

I'm in the process of creating a customize cloning so I have created `custom button` which will invoke from Standard page layout that will call the apex class... I can't use standard cloning functionality because I have other business rules that user will select (through config) which fields to be clone etc...

I'm stuck on how to populate the values from old record to new one.

the whole purpose of this is to make generic so no hard-coding any object name or fields or anything.

I have asked the question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165795/custom-button-redirecting-to-standard-page-in-edit-mode) you can have a look to get the context of my question or I can copy and past it here if needed.

I'm having issue with the code block:

> INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id

Understand that you can't have `Id` when you are inserting a new record and I get it but given this scenario what will be the case?

```
String objPrefix = sObjectId.getSobjectType().getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
SObject existRecord = Database.query(buildSOQL());
SObject newRecord = sObjectId.getSObjectType().newSObject(sObjectId);
newRecord = existRecord;

insert newRecord; //error
```

Any idea how would I (better) approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've kind of answered your own question in the title. You need to use the `SObject.clone` method. Note that you can *never* query for and subsequently insert a record, because it will already have an `Id` value.

**Incorrect**

```
newRecord = existingRecord;
insert newRecord;
```

**Correct**

```
newRecord = existingRecord.clone(/*preserveId*/ false);
insert newRecord;
```

There are a few other parameters you can set, all of which are optional:

> **Signature**
>   public sObject clone(Boolean preserveId, Boolean isDeepClone, Boolean preserveReadonlyTimestamps, Boolean preserveAutonumber)

You can read up on `SObject` methods in more detail [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm).

Comment: Thanks will take a look at the SObject but one quick question will this `SObject.clone` will get cloned only the fields that pulled or will it be entire object fields? as I said I have a requirement that I need to pull certain fields not entire from the object. thanks a lot

Comment: @NickKahn It will only clone fields in memory, I believe. In fact, it won't even copy *all* fields in memory without specifying additional parameters (`preserveReadonlyTimestamps`, `preserveAutonumber`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55945/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-nick-kahn).